# Is the word "Interface" in "Application Programming Interfaces" misleading?

Tags: java

As a newcomer in Java, and especially in JavaEE, I try to be as correct as possible in the words I use. I understand that an Interface is a series of abstract methods. On the other side, an Application Programming Interface is "a collection of prewritten packages, classes, and interfaces with their respective methods, fields and constructors". Am I wrong if I understand that API has not so much to do with Interfaces and could be called "Java Libraries" ? And that the use of the word Interface is, to say the least, confusing ?

Comment: Just to note: because you are confused, does not mean the terminology is confusing. You do not represent the entire world. It is more likely that you simply need a more structured way of researching. Let me guess: you've been searching the internet? That gigantic ball of chaos?

Comment: `Am I wrong if I understand that API has not so much to do with Interfaces and could be called "Java Libraries" ? ` , yes you are absolutely wrong. There are many predefined interfaces (usually) in the api that you have to implement and only then your class will be able to access those particular functionalities. For example to use threads in java you make your class implement `Runnable` and only then you can pass objects of your class to `Thread` constructor and create new thread of execution.

Comment: It is not confusing, the actual meaning depends on the context where the word [interface](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interface) is used. An interface is the point of interconnection or interaction between two enties or systems. For example where a user interracts with  software is generally refered to as (grafical) user *interface*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you will face this terminology error everywhere. `Library`, `API` and `Framework`.

What you are asking,

> **Interface**: In computing, an interface is a shared boundary across which two separate components of a computer system exchange information. The exchange can be between software, computer hardware, peripheral devices, humans and combinations of these.

This is by Wikipedia, This actually means, in Programming Languages like, `Java`, `C++`, `Php` or any other, it relates to isolating the layers from others. For example, You might need to access `USB` drive but for this, you won't use the core `Java` code, going deep into the Microprocessor or Micro-controller level. So, you will use any `Java` interface to achieve the same thing.

Whereas, when it comes to **`Application Programming Interface`** (`API`): then it is more application specific, not like `Java` interface which is more generic. For example, you are making an application which interacts with its own database, and you do not wish any third party application to interact with your database directly, but you want them to access your application, then you create an `API` for your application, which will act as a communication method for any third-party application to interact with your resources, safely, because you have exposed those methods.